# Automatically wrap post image in div

Tags: customization, attachments, uploads, images

*In regards to image attachments inserted into a post*, I would like to wrap the **img** tag inside a **div** tag for specific design purpose.

Is there a way to do this **automatically** after attaching the image file, like through *hooks/filters* maybe?

Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [image_send_to_editor](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/includes/media.php#L103) filter:

```
if(is_admin()){

  add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'wrap_my_div', 10, 8);

  function wrap_my_div($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt){
    return '<div class="mydiv" id="mydiv-'.$id.'">'.$html.'</div>';
  }
}
```

For existing images/posts you can try the regex in the function below

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Been sidetracked. Anyway, thank you very much for this. Exactly what I'm looking for! Though funny thing is that when I delete the image, the **div** element seems to remain. Changing it to **span** seems to fix it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Not looked into hooks and filters, but it is easily achievable by css alone.

Using the `2010 theme` and **class="entry-content"** as the  css selector

In your stylesheet use:

```
.entry-content img {  
/* do all your funky css attributes for the image in here */  
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but not really what I was after. I was trying to automatically wrap the image within another tag, eg. span, to achieve certain purpose. @one-trick-pony's solution above did the trick. Thanks for the reply, anyway. Cheers!