# Add a span tag around image

Tags: images

I want to be able to add a `<span></span>` around every image that gets posted.  How will I be able to do this?

Comment: You could do that with Jquery. See this thread for some guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987422/jquery-add-tag-a-around-img

Comment: do you want to do this when you save the post to the database, or when you show the post?

Comment: I would prefer not using jQuery to achieve this... I looked into this thread, but was unable to get this to work even after editing the core files: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/automatically-wrap-post-image-in-div

I want this to show when it is rendered on the page.  The tags are used for styling and I do not want to add the <span> tag in the html editor every time a new image is added.

Comment: Additional clarification: When I create a new post and upload an image, a span tag should automatically be wrapped around the image.  Ideally, I want to stay away from adding it in the embedded html editor.

Comment: `<span>` is typically considered an inline element so you might not want to wrap *all* your images in such tags. If you want to achieve some specific effect, consider defining a shortcode for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

try to add a filter function to functions.php of your theme;

example:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'alc_image_spanner');

  function alc_image_spanner($text) {
    $text = preg_replace_callback("#<img(.*?)>#is", create_function('$matches', 'return "<span><img".$matches[1]."></span>";'), $text);
    return $text;
  }
```