# Is there any hook to change media html in post?

Tags: plugins, posts, images

When I add image to a post, wordpress makes this html format in theme.

```
<p>
 <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-455" src="http://localhost/pb/wp-content/uploads/20116/04/huracan-yellow.jpg" alt="huracan yellow" width="2560" height="1440">
</p>
```

How can I change the above format to get possible html output like this, using hook or function:

```
<p>
 <div class="post-page-image">
  <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-455" src="http://localhost/pb/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/huracan-yellow.jpg" alt="huracan yellow" width="2560" height="1440">
 </div>
</p>
```

Edit: Tried image_send_to_editor filter on same and 2016 theme, but alteration or so found.

Comment: use `image_send_to_editor` hook!

Comment: @sumit, no success. It's giving same output html.

Comment: Did you try this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21003/32475) ?

Comment: yes, after using the same I commented.

Comment: Then please debug because that is working example!

Comment: Does this filter gives intended output on theme post page?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your functions.php - it will wrap the image in the div you want.

```
function filter_image_send_to_editor($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt) {
 return '<div class="post-page-image" id="image-'.$id.'">'.$html.'</div>';
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'filter_image_send_to_editor', 10, 8);
```

Comment: Thanks @Howard, I have tried the same as Sumit has told. I am not getting the intended changes. I have none of the plugins installed too. How can I debug this thing?

Comment: What is the text output from the editor when you do this?

Comment: Editor shows the same first html code I mentioned in the question after running this script.

Comment: Where are you putting the code?

Comment: This is my functions.php: http://pastebin.com/x5uVd2fc

Comment: I added your functions from the *Add Credit to Image * and beyond, and it adds the credit URL to the add media box, and wraps the image tag in a div.  Maybe try using a plain WP theme like 2016, and add the function to see if it works right.  Sounds like you have something conflicting either a plugin or theme setting.

Comment: Changed the theme and tested, no success. Maybe, I should try the_content filter.